# How to limit length of SearchView input text? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I have an searchview. How can I limit its input length in Kotlin? I want to max 6 length. Answered questions was in java and I couldn't convert it to my code.

**SearchView**

I bind searchview with databinding and give listeners.

```
searchViewFiyatInput = binding.fiyatInputEditText
    searchViewFiyatInput.setOnQueryTextListener(object : androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            query?.let {
                try {
                    binding.elmasText.text = (query.toDouble()*2.63).toInt().toString()
                    binding.elmasTextOnImage.text = (query.toDouble()*2.63).toInt().toString()
                    binding.fiyatOnImage.text = query.toInt().toString()
                } catch (e: Exception){
                    binding.elmasText.text = ""
                    binding.elmasTextOnImage.text = ""
                    binding.fiyatOnImage.text = ""
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            newText?.let {
                try {
                    binding.elmasText.text = (newText.toDouble()*2.63).toInt().toString()
                    binding.elmasTextOnImage.text = (newText.toDouble()*2.63).toInt().toString()
                    binding.fiyatOnImage.text = newText.toInt().toString()
                } catch (e: Exception){
                    binding.elmasText.text = ""
                    binding.elmasTextOnImage.text = ""
                    binding.fiyatOnImage.text = ""
                }
            }
            return true
        }
    })
```

**XML**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                    android:id="@+id/fiyatInputEditText"
                    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    app:searchIcon="@null"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    />
```

**Update**

I try to filter but there is no `.filters` method.

```
searchViewFiyatInput.filters =
        arrayOf<InputFilter>(LengthFilter(6))
```

or

```
(searchViewFiyatInput as TextView).filters= arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(6))
```

didn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```java
TextView et = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.fiyatInputEditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(6)});
```

For kotlin (using data binding):

```kotlin
binding.fiyatInputEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(6))
```

Comment: I convert it to Kotlin, but there is no .setFilters method. I update the code.

Comment: So you can use:  .filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(6)).I edit it in my answer.It gonna be work like this way

Comment: `.filters` not work again. There is not such a method for it.

Comment: you have to cast it to textview then your problem is gonna be done

Comment: `(searchViewFiyatInput as TextView).filters= arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(6))` like this? It gives `java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView` error.